# Docker push and pull using separate credentials

Tags: docker, authentication, docker-swarm

I am trying to create separate push and pull for docker registry in terms of safety reasons. Is it possible to create it in any of the container registries.

Answer (score 3):

Docker Registry 2.0 introduced a new, token-based authentication and authorization protocol. ACL is supported if you use [token based authentication](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#token) for the docker registry. You can use a pre-built ACL solution like this https://github.com/cesanta/docker_auth.
It porvides fine grained ACL rules, e.g.

```
acl:
  - match: {account: "admin"}
    actions: ["*"]
    comment: "Admin has full access to everything."
  - match: {account: "user"}
    actions: ["pull"]
    comment: "User \"user\" can pull stuff."
  # Access is denied by default.
```

see full example https://github.com/cesanta/docker_auth/blob/master/examples/simple.yml

For your scenario you can create two users with push and pull permissions only, then login as appropriate user for the operation (push or pull).

If you use Docker Hub, there is already sort of ACL for organisations.

> Docker Hub organizations let you create teams so you can give
>   colleagues access to shared image repositories. A Docker Hub
>   organization can contain public and private repositories just like a
>   user account. Access to **push** or **pull** for these repositories is
>   allocated by defining teams of users and then assigning team rights to
>   specific repositories. Repository creation is limited to users in the
>   organization owner’s group. This allows you to distribute limited
>   access Docker images, and to select which Docker Hub users can publish
>   new images.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/orgs/#repository-team-permissions

> Permissions are cumulative. For example, if you have Write
>   permissions, you automatically have Read permissions:
>
> - **Read access** allows users to view, search, and pull a private    repository in the same way as they can a public repository.
> - **Write access** allows users to push to non-automated repositories on    the Docker Hub.
> - **Admin access** allows users to modify the repositories “Description”,    “Collaborators” rights, “Public/Private” visibility
>     and “Delete”.

In your scenario you must have at least two registered hub users, then one of them could be a member of a team with **Read** only permissions, the other user could be a member of a team with **Write** (and automatically **Read**) access.

> Note: A User who has not yet verified their email address only has
>   Read access to the repository, regardless of the rights their team
>   membership has given them.

Comment: Can I use this with dockerhub ( the default docker registry).

Comment: not exactly this, but docker hub has some permission settings https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/orgs/#repository-team-permissions